# SOAP API Basic Authentication in C# only supported by .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, soap, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement Basic Authentication to my SOAP Web API, but my project is using .NET 4.6.2 Framework.

Looking through all the samples available in the Internet, seems like Basic Authentication uses .NET Core Framework.

Just want to know that is there any samples for Basic Authentication for .NET 4.6.2 framework SOAP Web API project?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication

Comment: You can get all the official [authentication sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code). Let me know if you require any firther assistance.